# Attempting to open SQL Connection from console application - conn.open dies

Tags: c#, database-connection, console-application

My code gets to conn.Open and gives me "Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll"

Here is the block of code:

```
        _timer.Stop();
        string path = @"C:\testlog.log";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYDB_Conn"].ConnectionString);
        string query = "SELECT RawImportEnabled, ImportDayTimeStamp from Settings";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open(); // Dies here
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Share with us the full error message and stack trace.

Comment: Write access to the root will be denied under usual circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            _timer.Stop();
        string path = @"C:\testlog.log";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYDB_Conn"].ConnectionString);
        string query = "SELECT RawImportEnabled, ImportDayTimeStamp from Settings";
        conn.Open(); // Dies here again.
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
```

Comment: Never mind, it is a connection error, cannot use trusted, must use SQL Server Connection User. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Order is missing ...first open connection then use sql command

```
_timer.Stop();
        string path = @"C:\testlog.log";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYDB_Conn"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open(); // sholud be here

        string query = "SELECT RawImportEnabled, ImportDayTimeStamp from Settings";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Besides your code is not formatted either..Format like this

```
 string path = @"C:\testlog.log";
            String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYDB_Conn"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open(); // sholud be here

                string query = "SELECT RawImportEnabled, ImportDayTimeStamp from Settings";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                { 
                    String RawImportEnabled = Convert.ToString(reader["RawImportEnabled"]);
                    //Do some thing
                }
            }
```

This has some benefits like debugging the connection string by putting a breakpoints ,Disposal of connection  without worrying for using statements etc

Comment: Tried modifying the code, still hangs at conn.Open()
 Let me post modified code as answer so it formats right.

Comment: Check your connection string with my code by putting a break point and run with debugging